# LAMP SERVER - BEST Redundant Fail over/Load balancing Setup

Tags: web-server

I am running LAMP application server and planning to implement Redundant/Fail over/Load balancing Setup.Can someone give me some insights in designing the solution?

Any help..thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ganesh

Comment: This topic is well covered on such a general basis: http://serverfault.com/search?q=lamp+high+availability

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how many servers you have. I'll suppose that you have two.

With 2 servers you can do e.g. the following:

- create an external DNS records that point to 2 different IP addresses
- assign these 2 IP addresses to 2 cluster services
- the master node of the 2 cluster services should be on different machines

This takes care for the redundancy on the webserver level. There are other solutions as well and depending on your availability/load balancing needs you can skip parts of the above 3 steps.

Regarding MySQL the best solution depends on the read/write characteristics of the application. Check the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html) for a starting point and implement either a MySQL cluster or a replicated MySQL database.

Comment: +1: saves me explaining again why round-robin is the right solution for load-balancing / failover.